# Update existing variable value using perl

Tags: perl

---

I have sample.ini file

Sample.ini

```
[Section1]
workers=3
port=8500
;
[Section2]
student=7
port=7688
;
```

How to read workers value from Section1 and update to workers=8

Expected result

[Section1]
   workers=8
   ...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Module. I think its exaclty what you want: [Config::IniFiles](http://www.p3rl.org/Config%3a%3aIniFiles)

```
use Config::IniFiles;
$cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => "Sample.ini" );
$value = $cfg->val( 'Section1', 'workers' );
$value = $value + 5;
$cfg->setval( "agent", "numworkers", $value );
$cfg->WriteConfig( 'agent.ini', -delta => 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks you 
Code works:
use Config::IniFiles;
$cfg=Config::IniFiles->new(-file=>"Sample.ini");
$value=$cfg->val('Section1','workers');
$value=$value+5;
$cfg->setval("agent","numworkers",$value);
$cfg->WriteConfig('agent.ini', -delta=>1);

Comment: Please add the actual answer.

Comment: @SithikSweetRascal if Paulchenkiller's Answer helped you out, mark his answer as correct please!